# Jenkins + Tycho: propagating update sites

Tags: jenkins, tycho, p2

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to "publish" p2 update sites in Jenkins (built with Tycho) so that they can easily be accessed in downstreams jobs? Currently I'm doing it semi-manually using Jenkins support for copying artifacts between jobs, and then specifying a repository-mirror element in a job-specific settings.xml which refers to the artifacts copied into the job, but this is all a little tricky and requires configuring jobs and build settings in a number of different places.

Is there any nicer way short of using an external solution such as Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution involving a repository manager that I am aware of is to use a Nexus and the [Unzip Plug-in](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin). (Disclaimer: The Unzip Plug-in is provided by the Tycho project, of which I am a committer.)

With such a setup, you could have one job deploy an update site to Nexus, and the next job use the update site via the unzip URL of the deployed site. Example: If the site was deployed under the GAV *project.abc:site:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT*, you could then access it via *http://<nexus>/content/repositories/<unzip-repo-name>/project/abc/site/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/site-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-unzip/*.

Note that you are slightly less flexible with such a setup that with what you have set up now: You need to have a version number for what your upstream project is building, so this may become tricky if you have multiple feature branches developing towards the same release version.

If you don't need this, you have the benefit of getting a portable build of your downstream project, i.e. developers build the project in the same way as your Jenkins does.

Comment: Artifactory has support for Jenkins publishing p2 update sites directly. But I was wondering about a solution which did *not* involve an external repository manager. :)

Comment: One specific feature I would like to have is for Jenkins to automatically direct me to the right build for upstreams builds. In other words, if project A triggers project B, I'd like for B to be able to refer to the exact build which triggered the job.